# AWS DynamoDB querying with values in an array

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-nodejs

With the following (TableName: "Table"):

```json
[
 {
  name: "name1",
  values: ["string1", "string2"]
 },
 {
  name: "name2",
  values: ["string1", "string2", "string3"]
 }
]
```

My partition key would be `name`, without any sort key. I am trying to query all the items with the same `value` field. The following is what I have tried:

```js
docClient.query({
      TableName: "Table",
      KeyConditionExpression: "name = :name",
      FilterExpression: "contains(values, :value)",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":name": "certain_name",
        ":value": "string1",
      },
    });
```

Suppose I want to query all the items with the `value` field of "string1". However, AWS DynamoDB requires the `partition key` which is unique for all my items. Are there any ways to query all the items with the same `value` field, without bothering about the `partition key`?

Or would a better approach be to just get all the items from DynamoDB, and just query with my own methods?

Thank you everyone!

Comment: In that case you need a `Scan` operation which basically loads each and every entry in your database (and bills that access) and then filters the results

Comment: Thank you for your answer @luk2302, i would try this method!

Comment: It works! I used the .scan() method with the JS `aws-sdk` library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to make it work by using the `.scan()` method from the `aws-sdk`.

```js
const attributName = "values";
const attributeValue = "string1";

docClient.scan({
  TableName: "Table",
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":attribute": attributeValue,
  },
  FilterExpression: `contains(${attributName}, :attribute)`,
});
```

Comment: You should not be depending on scan for production, it is extremely slow as it needs to scan the whole table to return what you queried for.

Answer (score 3):

For that query pattern you should probably reconsider your data model, I'd suggest something like this:

| PK | SK | GSI1PK | GSI1SK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NAME#name1 | VALUE#val1 | VALUE#val1 | NAME#name1 |
| NAME#name1 | VALUE#val2 | VALUE#val2 | NAME#name1 |
| NAME#name1 | VALUE#val3 | VALUE#val3 | NAME#name1 |
| NAME#name2 | VALUE#val1 | VALUE#val1 | NAME#name2 |

PK and SK are the partition and sort key of the base table and there is a Global Secondary Index "GSI1" which has GSI1PK as the partition and GSI1SK as the sort key.

**Get All Values By Name** would be something like this:

```
Query(KeyConditionExpression: PK = "NAME#<name>")
```

This returns a list of all values.

**Get All Names By Value** could be done like this:

```
Query(KeyConditionExpression: GSI1PK = "VALUE#<value>", Index: GSI1)
```

This returns a list of all names.

This pattern is called an inverted index and you could in principle also define the Global Secondary Index with the partition key as SK and sort key as PK in order not to duplicate the attributes.

The `NAME#` and `VALUE#` prefixes could also be omitted, but it's good practice if you're using a single table design.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, wouldn't this structure take up more space? For example, if a single user have 6 `values`, it would take up 6 items worth of space.

Comment: Yes, but storage is cheaper than compute, which is why NoSQL patterns are around ;-)

Comment: @Maurice To further dig into that, how does it affect things if there are a significant amount of other fields.  It's one thing to refactor the DB structure around a single array with a trivial data structure -- but what if each element was considerably more complex and had other sub-arrays and sub-objects?  I could see a single 'item' easily turning into hundreds of DB 'rows'?  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @lowcrawler That could happen, but then you're maybe not using the right tool or data model for the job. Can't say much about this without a concrete problem.